# non-volatile virtual memory for C++ containers

Tags: c++, architecture, database, memory

Is there a virtual memory management process that would allow a program to use the standard container structures and classes, but retain these structures and their data when the program is not running (or being used), for use by the program at a later time?
This should be possible, but can it be done without changing the source code and its (container) declarations?
Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There have been a [couple](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184410517) of [projects](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.57.9542) along this line. Neither of those seems to have come into particularly wide use. [Stxxl](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the most widely used of the projects along this line.